# Toggle show/hide and replace div content at same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a project where I have a row of product boxes with a button to "View Products" which I need to show a hidden div onclick which contains all the products. When the hidden div is shown, I'd like the content in the div that held the product brand (and "View products" link) to change to just show the product logo and a "HIDE ALL" button.

I have the show/hide toggle working using the script below but not sure how to get the content of the div with the button in it to change and add the toggle to the "HIDE" button? Also, when clicking on another "VIEW Products" button, the other product box should return to the original. I've attached an idea of what I'm doing as I realise my description is probably a little confusing  - 'screen1.gif' shows the row of boxes/brands - 'screen2.gif' shows what happens when you click on a brand and that brands other products appear below.

Screen 1 - http://hoohoots.com/dev/screen1.gif
Screen 2 - http://hoohoots.com/dev/screen2.gif

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks,
David

Show/Hide toggle script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if (e.style.display == 'block') e.style.display = 'none';
    else e.style.display = 'block';

    hideAllBut(id);
}

function hideAllBut(id) {
var lists = document.querySelectorAll('.reveal');
for (var i = lists.length; i--; ) {
    if (lists[i].id != id) {
        lists[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: your current code can be rewritten as `function toggle_visibility(id) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#' + id).toggle();
    hideAllBut(id);
}

function hideAllBut(id) {
    $('.reveal').not('#' + id).hide();
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a start.  I tried to keep the same structure that you had.

HTML - Add a `this` to reference the clicked element for each `btn_view link` `onclick="toggle_visibility('all-product-one',this);"`

E.G.

```
<div class="btn_view"><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('all-product-one',this);">VIEW ALL</a></div>
```

jQuery

```
function toggle_visibility(id,el) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.btn_view a').html('VIEW ALL');
    $('.price-text').show();
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if (e.style.display == 'block') 
    {
        e.style.display = 'none';
        $(el).html('VIEW ALL');
    }
    else 
    {
        e.style.display = 'block';
        $(el).html('HIDE ALL');
        $(el).parent().parent().find('.price-text').hide();
        //$(el).parent().prev('.price-text').hide();
    }

    hideAllBut(id);
}
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/d2cXB/9/

Comment: Thanks Trevor, this is a great help... much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a css class in like this:

```
.clicked{
    background-color:black;
    // other css code here
}
```

then, when the div gets clicked just add this class to the div, you can use jquery to do this too.

Comment: Any chance of seeing it written in a fiddle as I'm a bit of a noob on jQuery?

Comment: this is how you add a class to an element in jquery: $('#ELEMENTID').addClass("clicked");

Comment: Thanks. How would it be written so that when the "VIEW PRODUCTS" button on products box 4 for example is clicked, then the small products box 2 reverts back to it's original state?

Comment: this function removes the added classes from the element, so you can loop on you divs, remove the previously added class then re-add it to the newly clicked div, here is the function to remove the class: `$("#ELEMENTID").removeClass("clicked");`

Comment: Not sure that'll work in this case as it's not really a class I'm changing, I'm toggling between two divs - hidden  div shows when button is clicked and hidden again when another button for another product range is clicked

Comment: can you show me how are you doing it on jsfiddle? maybe I can help

Comment: Ok cheers, I'll strip out the code I have and put it in to a fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d2cXB/8/ (Fiddle working ok in Chrome). Stripped it back to basic.

Comment: here try this code, it is a start though: http://jsfiddle.net/shahe_masoyan/d2cXB/15/